# How to make a tab bar application out of standalone NIBs?

Tags: ios, user-interface, nib, tabbar

I have 5 standalone table view controller `nibs` (with custom cell implementation) accessible through an another table view menu list (no storyboards)

The client desires to have all 5 `nibs` in tabs. So I need to get rid of the menu list and provide `nibs` in TABs .

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add this property to your `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

make a method to set the views and set up your tabbar like:

```
-(void)setViews
{
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    [navigationController1.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    [navigationController2.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    [navigationController3.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
    [navigationController4.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController5=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController5];
    [navigationController5.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    [navigationController1.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    [navigationController2.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    [navigationController3.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    [navigationController4.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    [navigationController5.navigationBar setHidden:YES];


    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar"];
    [[[self tabBarController]tabBar]setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"]];
    [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1, navigationController2,navigationController3,navigationController4,navigationController5];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
```

avoid the set images and `setHidden` if you don't want to or not want to make the custom navigation bar.
and call this method in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Now set up the delegate method for tabbar and you can set the custom images over there:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-1"];
    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1)
    {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-2"];
    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2)
    {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-3"];
    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3)
    {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-4"];
    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 4)
    {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-5"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd set it all up in the main nib/storyboard, but it's easier to show in code.  You can create the view controllers in the usual way (again, nib or storyboard or code).

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5] animated:YES];
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window;
    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```